# Using css3 and Jquery to make 3d effect for images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i'm looking for the css3 or something to make images 3d effect like Cover Flow.
Because i cant upload my example to this topic so [here](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/akCswT8UXeu5Vnz-gWSv-A?feat=directlink) is the image shape i wanna make.

Can you show me how to do like this ? 
Thanks.

Comment: the link doesn't work - "Sorry, that page was not found."

Comment: maybe you are looking for [this](http://paulbakaus.com/lab/js/coverflow/)

Comment: sorry about that, i uploaded to picasa but i forgot edit to share everybody, so here is the shape that i wanna the images looks like ( use css3 or jQuery ) [here](https://picasaweb.google.com/104510000881746957232/September42011#5648451147234859842)

Comment: thanks to Samich and Arnaud Leymet but the demo you show me the shape of images dont like what i want, i still looking for, do you have some ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for the css3 or something to make images 3d effect like Cover Flow

As samish wrote, you should have a look at the following demo:

**[Coverflow effect featuring CSS transformations and jQuery UI](http://paulbakaus.com/lab/js/coverflow/)**

Comment: thank you but the shape of images dont like what i want it be, it must be like [here](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/akCswT8UXeu5Vnz-gWSv-A?feat=directlink)

Comment: sorry about that, i uploaded to picasa but i forgot edit to share everybody, so here is the shape that i wanna the images looks like ( use css3 or jQuery ) [here](https://picasaweb.google.com/104510000881746957232/September42011#5648451147234859842)
Thanks for all.